# Get all Facebook page photos tagged by others

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, photo, tagging

I can get all photos uploaded by admin like [this](https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/photos/):

But how can I get all Facebook page photos tagget by others users (only allowed on facebook page timeline) in Graph API v2.3?

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you mean by "get all Facebook page photos tagged by other users". Can you provide an example Graph API call that illustrates what you have in mind (even in the example API call does not work)?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/tagged/photos/ . I need to get just tagged photos from Facebook page. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for the `/page` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) lists all the edges that you can query on a page object.
One of them is `/page/photos`, which is [documented here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/).

As the ["Reading" section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Reading) on that page explains, this edge will return a set of `Photo` objects, which in turn is [documented here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/photo).

In the Photo docs, you can read that there is a [`tags`-edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/photo#edges) on photo objects, which contains the information about who is tagged at what position in the photo. The [docs for photo tags are here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/photo/tags/)

There is also a field `name_tags` on `Photo` objects, which is documented to be "An array containing an array of objects mentioned in the `name` field.", where the `name` field is "The user provided caption given to this photo."

When making a query to `/page-id/photos`, you will receive both the `tags` data and the `name_tags` data by default, but you can request these explicitly as well by using the `fields` request parameter in your graph API call:

```
curl -G \
-d "access_token=YOUR_TOKEN" \
-d "fields=tags,name_tags" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/cocacola/photos"
```

Your app can then process the results and find those tags that are of interest to you.